# connecting to google cloud with codeigniter on appengine

Tags: codeigniter, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

i'm using codeigniter on google appengine ,

my issue is that appengine is unable to run query on the cloud sql ,

the my app on the appengine is able to connect to the cloud sql,

i have same setting in my local host and it's able to connect and run query on cloud sql,

i tried to debug the query function in the codeigniter , and i confirmed that both my appengine and my application in my local host are using the same exact query :

```
SELECT *
FROM (`grs_user`)
WHERE `username` =  'Admin'
AND `password` =  '*******'
AND `is_published` =  'True'
```

i confirmed this by printing out the `$sql` var in `get_where()` function inside `DB_active_rec.php` .

database.php :

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = null;
$db['default']['database'] = 'fsm';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = 'grs_';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '#__';
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['cachedir'] ='';
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['socket'] = '/cloudsql/fsmocs:asia-east1:fsm';
```

database name is correct ,

anyone had such issue ?

Comment: how can i print out the error in codeigniter ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with codeigniter but I can help with the Cloud SQL / MySQL error if I can see what the error is.

Comment: i found where the sql is being excuted ,
i have the following :

 `function _execute($sql)
 {
  $sql = $this->_prep_query($sql);
   
  $result = mysqli_query($this->conn_id, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($this->conn_id)) ;
 
  
  return $result;
 }` 

it's died but no error showed up on the browser , 

so the query is failing , but looks like the SQL server is not returning errors ,

Comment: It's very unlikely that there would not be any errors -- even if the server didn't return an error, it's likely the client would generate some kind of error with more information. Can you try looking at the web server logs and see if there's any more information there?

Answer (score 0):

after using the first generation SQL it's working now ,
i used same setting and same DB .sql file .